# Ionic and Cordova won't update version number

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, npm

After running `sudo npm install -g cordova ionic`. It runs fine and doesn't throw any errors but when I use `ionic --version` or `cordova --version` it returns the previous version number. After looking online I can't find a specific resolution to my issue.

After uninstalling everything(node, cordova, ionic) the terminal still returns as if everything except npm commands.

I've looked through Finder but I can't find anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you run `ionic info` in your project folder and add the output to your question please? Could help solving the riddle. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can install specific version of Ionic using following command -

```
npm install -g ionic@1.6.4
```

To uninstall Ionic and Cordova you need to uninstall globally like -

```
npm uninstall -g ionic
```